# get matched key in Object.keys(obj)

Tags: javascript

I have an object containing team members.

If the `incomingMessage` contains one of the keys then I want to return one of the messages about them.

Is there a way I can get the matched key in the code below?

```js
const team = {
  hank: ['good guy', 'wonderful man'],
  chuck: ['jerk', 'buttmunch']
}

let incomingMessage = 'tell me about chuck';

if(Object.keys(team).indexOf(incomingMessage) > -1) {
  console.log(team);
  //is there a way here that I can get the 
  //key that has matched? so in this case, 'chuck'
}
```

Comment: You would need to look for the key in the message, not the message in the key.

Comment: This would make more sense as a straight for loop: for each key, if the key is in the message, show the result. Or you could write something to parse the name from the message, then it's just a key lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Logic is backwards ... you need to check if the key exists in the message , not the other way around.

Something like:

```
Object.keys(team).forEach(function(key) {
   if (incomingMessage.indexOf(key) > -1){
      console.log('Found ' + key +' in message')
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `for in` loop to loop over the properties of the team and then use `indexOf` in it.

```
const team = {
  hank: ['good guy', 'wonderful man'],
  chuck: ['jerk', 'buttmunch']
}

let incomingMessage = 'tell me about chuck';

for (var member in team) {
  if (incomingMessage.indexOf(member) > -1) {
      console.log(team[member]); // your team member information array
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrRecTeam = incomingMessage.split(' ');
var arrTeam = Object.keys(team)


arrTeam.forEach((val, key) => console.log("found at", arrRecTeam.indexOf(val)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is reversed, you need to look for the key in the string, not the string in the key.

```js
const team = {
  hank: ['good guy', 'wonderful man'],
  chuck: ['jerk', 'buttmunch']
}

const msgCheck = (msg) => Object.keys(team).filter((k) => msg.indexOf(k) > -1)

console.log(msgCheck('tell me about chuck'))
console.log(msgCheck('tell me about hank'))
console.log(msgCheck('tell me about chuck and hank'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const team = {
  hank: ['good guy', 'wonderful man'],
  chuck: ['jerk', 'buttmunch']
}

var incomingMessage = 'tell me about chuck';

if(incomingMessage.indexOf(Object.keys(team)) > -1) {
  alert(team);
  //is there a way here that I can get the 
  //key that has matched? so in this case, 'chuck'
}
```